# How can I confirm the version of magento? without have ftp access?

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to now the version of the magento of this website:

http://www.aztime.com.br/loja

its possible check it without ftp access, without admin panel access, without licence.txt, just like a visitor?

Comment: Its not duplicated, its a different question.

Comment: This answer here says it all: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/60681/3326