# How http://magentoversion.com determines Magento version ?

Tags: version

How http://magentoversion.com works ? Is there any similar tool to check Magento version accurately ?

I found a tool call magescan. It is good but it is failing for some of the websites which magentoversion.com is able to find.

Comment: Not sure, but they won't be around for long at that domain.

Answer (score 0):

@kalyan, they is one way to find the version `www.websiteurl/downloader` then you can get version at bottom else go though url `https://www.magereport.com`

Answer (score 0):

One addon is available in chrome.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/version-check-for-magento/aekpbnbbbgocohlbdpdfgghamedmplal

I think easily find out based on copyright notice.

for reference : [Determine Magento version without access to code base](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60476/determine-magento-version-without-access-to-code-base?answertab=active#tab-top)