# How can I find out version info required to select correct update method?

Tags: upgrade, version

I have been asked to help a client upgrade their Magento site from v2.1.9 to v2.2.3 but from what I'm reading on the magento.com website so far, this sounds like a very complex process that depends on factors such as the installation method that was originally used for this instance of Magento and it requires more specific version info than I can find in the Magento admin pages. It appears attempting the upgrade without knowing this information is likely doomed to corrupting their installation.

How can I discover from looking at a Magento v2.1.9 website 1) whether it was installed by "cloning from github", "web setup wizard", or "command line"? and 2) whether their Magento v2.1.9 is a Magento v2.1.9EE or Magento v2.1.9 community edition / open source edition?

I have explored the Admin pages but the only version info I've found is "Magento ver. 2.1.9". Since the upgrade documents indicate it's critical to know this stuff before attempting an upgrade, I'm assuming it's here somewhere and I'm just missing it! If someone with more Magento experience could point me to the correct Admin page to see these details, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Magento Stack Exchange.

If you have SSH access or even SFTP of some sort:

1) Typically if cloned, you'll find a .git/ subdirectory under the main install path of Magento.
2) https://github.com/gwillem/magento-version-identification

References:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.12CE.html
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/upgrader/upgrade-main-pg.html
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/62966/69

Comment: Thanks. I could not find a .git subdirectory, however there is a .gitignore file in the doc root. How could I be sure the .git subdirectories weren't removed after the install? I also checked the method of determining the Magento version but that looks like a fairly arcane method - the website says their program had 91.7% accuracy at guessing the Magento version based on a study in 2015.  But it is useful to know that exists. If people are going to the trouble of writing programs to guess what version and type of Magento they have installed, maybe there's no direct way of finding out. :(

Comment: Ah! That last URL in your answer does have part of the needed info. If I hit /magento_version with a browser it reveals part of the version info like so: "Magento/2.1 (Community)"
It lacks the minor version number but I already know from the Admin pages that it's "ver 2.1.9" so I think I'm good on the version now. I assume it's 2.1.9 CE. Just need to discover the installation method now.